# Text Changes back to original when sound is finished playing?

Tags: android, onclick, media-player

I've created this simple soundboard app which plays a sound on click. I've also setup so that the text changes when the button is hit but is there anyway for the text to change back to its original when the sound file is finished playing

Thanks in advance!

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button aussi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aussi);
    aussi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(aussi.getText().toString().equals("Australian")){
                try{

                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            aussi.setText("Jay");

            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,
                    R.raw.aussi);
            mediaPlayer.start();

            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer play) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    play.release();

                }
            });

        }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the solution by yourself, the completion listener tells you when the sound finishes playing. so :

```
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer play) {

                play.release();
                // Now you can set you text
                aussi.setText("your original text");

            }
        });
```